# NoClassDefFoundError: MainMockTransformer when using PowerMock javaagent with jacoco

Tags: java, powermock, jacoco, javaagents

I was following [this](http://www.notonlyanecmplace.com/make-eclemma-test-coverage-work-with-powermock/) article to make jacoco work for classes using Powermock. In eclipse using the eclemma, i was able to see the correct code coverage. But we are on larger scale using sonar to measure the code coverage.

To generate the jacoco reports which are fed to sonar we have induced jacoco agent via VM args. An ant target runs the unit tests to generate the report.

These are my VM arguments:

```
-Xmx1048m -Xms1048m -XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
-javaagent:<somepath>\powermock-module-javaagent-1.6.1.
jar
-javaagent:<somepath>\jacocoagent.jar=
destfile=<somepath>\jacoco.exec,append=true,excludes=
com.google.*:com.sun.*:-Org.mockito.*:-Org.junit.*:
-Org.apache.*:junit.*,includes=*
-Ddeployed.server.type="tomcat" -noverify
```

Following the article, I also put the powermock agent into the javaoptions but I am getting below error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/powermock/core/transformers/impl/MainMockTransformer
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
   at org.powermock.modules.agent.PowerMockClassTransformer.<clinit>(PowerMockClassTransformer.java:41)
   at org.powermock.modules.agent.PowerMockAgent.<clinit>(PowerMockAgent.java:42)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
   at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```